# Interconnecting PHP web service server and C# win form application

Tags: c#, php, web-services

[image]

i have a web service developed with `PHP` bith (client and server ) using **nSoap** Libraries .. i required to connect the web services sever  to a `C#` winforms app to do the processing of the data which come to the server .. is it possible to do ?

connect to a web-service as a client in C# is fine but interconnect with the web service server ?

**PHP web service should consume the C# win forms app features !**

Comment: maybe you can specify your problem a bit more. "interconnecting" is very vague, try giving a bit of background. why can't you just talk to the web service server via the web service it exposes?

Comment: Unable to understand the problem, Do you want you winforms app to consume the service provided by the PHP web server?

Comment: If thats the case, you can just use the wsdl to generate a C# proxy and consume it from your winforms app.

Comment: Or if its the other way that you want the PHP web service to call your C# code, then you have to expose your C# functionality as a web service (or other middleware solutions like bus) and let PHP consume it - you can even make a REST based service which will be easy to call from the PHP code

Comment: PHP web service should consume the C# win forms app features !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used a  `SOAP` to solve this issue